# Required fields on Tab Page are not shown as error on save in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have two required fields in Tab Pages in TFS 2013, when I save the workItem it shows an error on top of the form, but it doesn't show where is the error field. (Pic1)
When I click on a tab page (no matter which one except the current) it will show Error sign on tab page (Pic2).

It is so complicated to teach all of our users to act like this, is there any solution or work around except moving the fields from tabs to header?

[image]
Pic1

[image]
Pic2

Comment: That seems odd, we have required fields on other tabs - :( -  and it works like you would expect. What version of VS (and updates), do you see the same in the Web Access? It might be client related, it might be how the validation rules are setup.

Comment: @DaveShaw We are using Vs2013+TFS2013, I will check the web access. Also I found a bug report about that in Microsoft site

Comment: @DaveShaw Yes, in Web Access it is the same.